# add_filter not working for returning logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a snippet to detect whether a user is logged in - if yes, then "My account" and "Logout" links show in top menu, if no, "Login" link shows.

It works fine, until a user logs in with "remember me" option checked, leaves my website without logging out and comes back.

Then "Login" shows on top menu, instead of "My account" and "Logout". It doesn't behave normally, after clicking it, user is not redirected to login page, but instead "My account" and "Logout" instantly show up. Also adding anything to the cart makes "My account" and "Logout" show up.

I checked via var_dump() that is_user_logged_(in) doesn't return anything until I click "Login" or add something to the cart. I tried changing priority to 1 or 9999 and it didn't help.

```
// Add login & logout buttons to secondary menu.
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
  if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
   $items .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' )) . '">My account</a></li>
              <li><a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ) . '">Logout</a></li>';
  }
  elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
   $items .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Login</a></li>';
  }
  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like that.
2 things that came to my mind.
Plugin messing up with it. Try disabling all plugins and switching to default theme. If its still issue, workaround is to go without filter by creatign 2 menus and showing correct one depending on the if(is_user_logged_in()).... that one should work 100%.